# Is Mi Yodeya a suited forum for a someone who converted to Judaism?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, stackexchange

Is Mi Yodeya suited for converts?

Comment: "Can I be here and ask questions?" For sure. Who gave you the impression otherwise?

Comment: What if you're a woman and a convert?

Comment: Everyone is welcome here, both to ask and to answer. Male, female, young, old, Jewish and not-Jewish. But maybe this question is better for Meta.

Comment: Wow amazing, thank you.

Comment: @Harel13 I'm going to be the one to say it..... If "everyone is welcome" that means that "nobody is not welcome" and if OP is named "nobody" then....... ;p

Comment: Is this better as a meta question? Is there an underlying halachic issue?

Comment: Hi nobody. Please clarify if you are asking about site policy or Jewish law.

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, I guess both because on one hand, I've seen women at Yeshiva University study Torah now, yet on the other hand I know a man and a woman should not be in a room together privately without the door open. What about a digital public place? Can I just ask question on here  and learn Torah without it being a halachic issue?

Comment: @JewishArt The issur of yichud (which you are reffering to) is for a man and woman to be in a room together. You bring up an interesting point as many gedolim have said there is an issur yichud to be in a room with an unfiltered phone/comupter (as it can lead to viewing innapropriate things), but I don't think there would be an issur yichud in digital spaces, thought hanging out with people of the opposite gender is defintely not recommended. 1/2

Comment: @JewishArt Regarding whether this is a good place for a ger - I think not. This site has a lot of well intentioned (and some not well intentioned) people saying things ranging from incorrect to kfira (denying Hashem's existence), this probably isn't a good place for anyone, let alone somebody who is in the process of learning - you don't want to be corrupted/misguided by things you see here. If you have any questions of any nature you should ask your rov (if you don't have a rov you should get one), I'd be happy to give you some resources if you are interested. 2/2

Answer (score 3):

Definitely yes, see the following text in the MI Yodeya [help pages](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-mi-yodeya).

> Mi Yodeya is a Q&A site for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.